# Javascript: replace <select> with <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to replace `<select>` tag to a `<div>` with hidden `<div>` that drops down when clicked?
Not a full solution, but maybe some js or jQuery library/plugin to do this. I can spend a day developing it, but maybe someone did have already did it?

The reason i need it is the joomla administrative interface — the dropdown list contains very long values, and i had to set fixed width to those `<select>`s

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried out quite a few select replacement JQuery plugins, and settled on [select-box](http://code.google.com/p/select-box/) - be sure to check out the [demo page](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) as well. There's a wide variety of plugins for this purpose, so if this one doesn't meet your needs I'm sure you'll find one that does with a little Google-fu.

Comment: That page from www.bulgaria-web-developers.com has its domain name expired today Apr 20, 2012.